# Ошибка при выполнении запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT lichniy_nomer, MAX(`sum`) FROM (
SELECT  lichniy_nomer, SUM(narushenie.shtraf)'sum' FROM protocol, narushenie
WHERE protocol.nomer_narusheniya=narushenie.nomer_narusheniya
GROUP BY (lichniy_nomer))t1
HAVING  MAX(`sum`) = (SELECT lichniy_nomer FROM (SELECT lichniy_nomer, MAX(`sum`) FROM (
SELECT  lichniy_nomer, SUM(narushenie.shtraf)'sum' FROM protocol, narushenie
WHERE protocol.nomer_narusheniya=narushenie.nomer_narusheniya
GROUP BY (lichniy_nomer))t1))
```

---

По задумке, данный запрос должен возвращать личный номер (исходя из максимальной суммы). Однако появляется ошибка:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.
```

Как исправить, не могу понять.

Comment: @pixma, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Да, [@smackmychi](/users/22959/smackmychi) прав, такие монструозные конструкции тут ни к чему.

```
select sum(n.shtraf) `sum`, p.lichniy_nomer
from protocol p 
  join narushenie n on n.nomer_narusheniya = p.nomer_narusheniya
group by p.lichniy_nomer
order by `sum` desc
limit 1
```

Или если хочется с вложениями:

```
select s.`sum`, p.lichniy_nomer
from protocol p 
  join (select nomer_narusheniya, sum(shtraf) `sum`
        from narushenie
        group by nomer_narusheniya
        order by `sum` desc
        limit 1) s
  on s.nomer_narusheniya = p.nomer_narusheniya
```

ЗЫ Ошибка #1248 говорит, что все подзапросы должны иметь псевдонимы... что логично и аккуратно.

Comment: Не проверял, но опыт подсказывает, что второй вариант будет намного быстрее работать, чем первый.

Поэтому здесь даже не "если хочется", а "лучше делать так".

Первый вариант - join`им таблицы, потом группируем, потом сортируем и только потом выводим ответ.

Второй же вариант - группируем, сортируем, возвращаем одну строку, по которой выполняем join.

Были случаи, когда сортировка не по индексу на join`е значительно ухудшала время (с доли секунды до пары минут). Т.е. группировка и сортировка во втором варианте отработают быстрее, а join по одному значению и за join можно не считать )

Comment: @BOPOH, не лучше. пока не собрана статистика и не озвучены количественные показатели по таблицам, об оптимизации говорить рано. в данном случае речь идет о простоте запроса, а не о скорости, поэтому возможны оба варианта. про оптимизацию ждем следующих вопросов от ТС.

Answer (score 1):

Для примера. Запрос:
`SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM table group by ID order by 2 desc limit 1;`
Вернет одну запись (limit 1) - идентификатор и сумму. Данная выборка сгруппирована по ID (group by ID) и отсортирована(order by) по убыванию (desc) второго столбца (order by 2), поэтому первая запись будет иметь максимальное значение суммы и соответствующий идентификатор. Практического опыта у меня в данной области нет, можно подождать ответа от кого-нибудь еще.

Answer (score 0):

> 1248 - Every derived table must have
> its own alias.
>
> Google translate: 
> 1248 - Каждая производная таблица должна иметь свой собственный псевдоним.

[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) написал все правильно, не стоит писать настолько страшные запросы для простых задач.